# addEventlistener to all new objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a cat constructor and I want to add eventListener to all my cat objects, so when I click on them, the counter increases. I don't want to add events one by one by hand. Is there any way to add event to all new objects? Thanks

```
var counter = document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML;

var Cat = function(name , source , width) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = new Image(width);
    this.image.src = source;
    document.body.appendChild(this.image);
}

var poplinre = new Cat("Poplinre" , "images/poplinre.jpg" , 500);
var chewie = new Cat("Chewie" , "images/chewie.jpg" , 500);
```

Comment: So add it inside of the cat function.... `this.image.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: One counter, shared with all the `Cat` instances? That's what the code above looks like...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes. They all share one counter. It's kinda like CowClicker game.

Comment: @epascarello I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Show what did not work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for click events globally and target only the images you want to. This way is called *Event Delegation*, this [article](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) gives you some explanation.

To be short, you listen the `click` event on a common parent node and targets only the wanted elements. In your situation you have to implement something like :

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
   if (e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'IMG' &&  e.target.classList.contains('cat')) {
       //only the image is targeted
    }
});

var Cat = function(name , source , width) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = new Image(width);
    this.image.src = source;
    this.image.classList.add('cat'); 
    document.body.appendChild(this.image);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices:

1. Add the handler individually, within the `Cat` constructor

   ```
   function incrementCounter() {
       document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = ++counter;
   }
   var Cat = function(name , source , width) {
       this.name = name;
       this.image = new Image(width);
       this.image.src = source;
       this.addEventListener("click", incrementCounter);
       document.body.appendChild(this.image);
   }
   ```
2. Use *event delegation*: Give your cat images some identifying characteristic (such as a class name) and have a single handler on the container they're being added to (`body` in this case), and put the handler on `body`, but have it do the increment only when the event passed through one your cat images:

   ```
   document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       if (e.target.closest(".cat")) {
           document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = ++counter;
       }
   });
   var Cat = function(name , source , width) {
       this.name = name;
       this.image = new Image(width);
       this.image.src = source;
       this.className = "cat";
       document.body.appendChild(this.image);
   }
   ```

#2 above uses [`Element#closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), which is vaguely new, but can be polyfilled for older environments.

Actually, in your **specific** case, you don't need `Element#closest` since `img` elements can't have descendant elements, so you could just look at `e.target.className` directly. `closest` is a more general solution (which also works here).

Answer (score 0):

See Event Delegation.

> Event delegation allows you to avoid adding event listeners to
>   specific nodes;  instead, the event listener is added to one parent.

[How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)